# Violation of sharpness in images (FitImage) kivi

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, kivy, kivymd

When I add a photo at the window creation stage, the images appear with low sharpness, but as soon as I change it in the application using MDFileManager, it becomes normal.

I tried to increase the size of the widgets to which I add photos and the sharpness begins to increase.On the left is a photo added via MDFileManager
[image]

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.clock import Clock
import os
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

KV = '''
<GaleryPhoto>:
    id: card_photo
    size: (220,220)
    size_hint: None, None

MDScreen:
    GaleryPhoto:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.25, "center_y": 0.5}
        on_press: self.add_photo(self)

    
    GaleryPhoto:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.75, "center_y": 0.5}

        
'''

class GaleryPhoto(MDCard):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: self.add_widget(FitImage(
                            source="path/to/image", 
                            radius=12,)
            ))

    def add_photo(self,instance):
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
                exit_manager=self.exit_manager, 
                select_path=self.select_path,
                preview = True,
                selector = 'file',
            )
        self.file_manager.show(
            os.path.expanduser("~"))  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path: str):
        self.exit_manager()
        image = FitImage(
            source=path,
            radius=12,
        )
        
        self.remove_widget(self.children[0])
        self.add_widget(image)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()  

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Example().run()
```